# calendar in android emulator with os version >= 2.2

Tags: android, android-emulator, calendar

is it possible to get a calendar in the android simulator for the OS version >= 2.2

Comment: but is it possible to get a calendar on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no calendar on Android emulators..

Answer (score 3):

check this:
[Issue 1389: add Calendar application to Android SDK](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1389) (Android project page on Google Code)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the apk with adb.

Not very convenient. Better to test directly on the phone...